# SNMP Manger Response PDU NULL when system time changed?

Tags: linux, snmp

I have a problem collecting health status from the SNMP Agent, when the system (the one where SNMP manager is installed) date/time is changed manually.

When this happens, the Response PDU comes back null and the SNMP manger is unable to display status even for next request/retry, until we restart the NMS or SNMP manger.

Restarting it works fine, with the updated system date/time.

Why does this happen, and how do I handle the situation when the system time gets changed? Do we always have to restart the SNMP manger when the system time is changed?

Comment: Do you use SNMP V3 ?

Comment: Can you run `ntpd(8)` on all your hosts and not bother with changing times again?

Answer (score 0):

So, how do you know that "the Response PDU" comes back null? If there is any evidence such as network packet capture, it unfortunately indicates a bug of the SNMP agent you used. Then you need to find its vendor and ask them to fix the issue?

If restarting the SNMP manager resolves the issue, then it may be a manager side issue (where the manager failed to handle agent side time change), and in that case you need to find the vendor of the manager to look into the issue.

Like @JPBlanc pointed out, in most cases this kind of issues is SNMP v3 based, so it is likely that you hit bugs of either the agent or the manager.